# Doctrine: Inject Entity into property of other Entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a class **Person** in re-usable bundle for my symfony project. In another bundle I have a class **FinancialRecord**.

Since I want to have the bundles decoupled, I have decided to add a property **personId** to FinancialRecord

Now loading a list of **FinancialRecords** I also need to have access to **Person**, so in my Controller:

```
$financialRecords = $em->getRepository('MyFinancialBundle:FinancialRecord')->findByYear($year);
foreach ($financialRecords as $key=>$financialRecord) {
    $person = $otherEm->getRepository('MyUserBundle:Person')->findOneById($financialRecord->getPersonId());
    $financialRecord->person = $person;
}
```

Basically what is happening here is that I am injecting person into FinancialRecord, so that I can access person in my twig-template. Note that 2 different Entity Managers are used.

Is there a way to combine the two entities into a single DQL-query? Currently my debug toolbar is stating that 490 queries have been executed because of this operation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, to create two independent bundles is to use interface for `Person` in your Financial bundle - `IPerson`. Later, in the code that includes the Person bundle you can map this interface to a particular entity using method described here - http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html